PHP memcached addserver don't return False when server is down
I have a memcached server running on 127.0.0.1:11211, but not 127.0.0.22:11212. I would like to test the connection to it thanks to this code;
$memcached = new Memcached;
if( !$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.22', 11212) )
    die( 'memcached server error' );
else
    echo 'OK';

The actual output is 'OK' instead of the expected 'memcached server error'
How to determine whether the memcached server is connected?

The memcache client will not make a connection to a server unless you're reading/writing to it. addServer returning true just means that the server is added to the pool, but it doesn't imply that a connection can be made.

If your goal is to determine whether the server is up & running, you can use this piece of code :
$cache = new Memcached();
$cache->addServer(‘127.0.0.1’,11211);
if ($cache->getStats()){
    echo ‘success’;
}else{
    echo ‘failed’;
}

Unfortunately, this will return false if ANY of the server is down (see https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/336)
